# App crashing in background when taking photo from camera in Oneplus

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an app with functionality of taking image from camera or gallery. This is working fine in all the devices but not in OnePlus.

This is the code :

```
public File dispatchTakePictureIntent(Activity activity) {
        File tempPhotoFile = null;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {

            try {
                tempPhotoFile = Utils.createImageFile(activity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (tempPhotoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, Utils.getFileProvider(activity), tempPhotoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                takePictureIntent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", photoURI));
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
        return tempPhotoFile;
    }
```

Code in Utils :

```
public static File createImageFile(Context context) throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        return image;
    }
```

Now the app is working fine in other devices. But in OnePlus when the camera opens and we click the image and the preview is shown, at that time in the logcat we see that the app is shown dead and its restarted and it opens on app home scree. when we go to the particular tab from where we open the camera app, we can see the state is saved and we land on the same page. How can we solve the issue?

Comment: Post crash logs to identify the issue

Comment: Please avoid posting code that is not complete, others need to write parts of the code: Utils, Constants to run your code. Also, provide the crash log from your logcat.

Comment: No log is being shown related to app. the app just restarts.

Comment: @Priyabrata added the code in Utils

Comment: @ParthAnjaria Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not give permission for your URI

please study that
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Edit fragment most important for you is
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#Permissions

somewhere before startActivityForResult you need to add

```
 activity.grantUriPermission(activity.getActivityInfo().getPackageName(), photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

that is pseudo code so please , check it on your side

EDIT 2: I've made a mistake with suggesting that you need to add that permission to your own package. You need to add it to app that will make that picture for you

heres kotlin code for catching all apps that can do it

```
val resInfoList = activity.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    resInfoList
            .map { it.activityInfo.packageName }
            .forEach { this.grantUriPermission(it, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) }
```

Also for image capturing you can use simpler Intent

```
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PICK_CAMERA_CODE)
```

cheers

Comment: permission is given. checked in the app setting page.

Comment: You need to call it in code, like it is described in FileProvider documentation and like I wrote to you that small piece of code

Comment: Yes I understand that, and that code has been written. The camera app opens and when i click the image that time the app in the background restarts and does not crash. there is no crash log.

Comment: you don't have it in your code. There is no line with "grantUriPermission"

Comment: Tried after adding the code before activity.startActivityforresult. still not working. And if this was the issue, then it should not work in all phones right?

Comment: I have 8.1.0 on my mi a2 device, which is working fine. but the one plus phone has 10.0 version.

Comment: What is "it.activityInfo.packageName"? what is "it"?

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: I do not know. You need to find that stack trace. Try uncheck in debug window "only selected application" an look for error logs

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on OP7Pro.

Here is the code I used for the test:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun createImageFile(context: Context): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    return File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    )
}

private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent(activity: Activity): File? {
    var tempPhotoFile: File? = null
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {

        try {
            tempPhotoFile = createImageFile(activity)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        if (tempPhotoFile != null) {
            val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                activity,
                applicationContext.packageName + ".fileprovider",
                tempPhotoFile
            )
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            takePictureIntent.clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", photoURI)
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        }
    }
    return tempPhotoFile
}
```

Then, called it like:

```
btnOpenCamera.setOnClickListener{
     val r = dispatchTakePictureIntent(this)
     imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(r?.path))
}
```

I have set the result in a imageview.

File Provider:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

@xml/provider_paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Following are my observations:

```
return tempPhotoFile
```

doesn't wait for the camera to take the picture and come back with the result.
It returns the path instantly as the call to `activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` is completed, where the image file might not have been created at the time of it returning the value. As a result, the behaviour is unpredictable.

To ensure that you have captured the image, you should rely on the onActivityResult
and get the data from the intent. I have found the same behaviour in other phones also with your code. I hope I have explained the problem clearly.

As to why your app is crashing, probably you are trying to do something with the file it is returning from `dispatchTakePictureIntent`, and when you try to process it, the image actually isn't created by that time. Hence, `Unable to open content: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/...`

This is assuming, you tried to use the file as an Image as I did.

[Here](https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954) is an example implementation you might want to look at.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Priyabrata

Answer (score 0):

Just add below property in the activity tag of the Manifest file.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

App pointing to Android 10, above flag is **false** by default. We have to set it to **true**.